# Pass hash to js with rails to generate a chart

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to generate a chart with the count of the new user registered to my site every day.

I'm using a js that take a variable to populate the chart, example:

```
var pageviews = [
                    [1, randValue()],
                    [2, randValue()],
                    [3, 2 + randValue()],
                    [4, 3 + randValue()],
                    [5, 5 + randValue()],
                    [6, 10 + randValue()],
                    [7, 15 + randValue()],
                    [8, 20 + randValue()],
                    [9, 25 + randValue()],
                    [10, 30 + randValue()],
                    [11, 35 + randValue()],
                    [12, 25 + randValue()],
                    [13, 15 + randValue()],
                    [14, 20 + randValue()],
                    [15, 45 + randValue()],
                    [16, 50 + randValue()],
                    [17, 65 + randValue()],
                    [18, 70 + randValue()],
                    [19, 85 + randValue()],
                    [20, 80 + randValue()],
                    [21, 75 + randValue()],
                    [22, 80 + randValue()],
                    [23, 75 + randValue()],
                    [24, 70 + randValue()],
                    [25, 65 + randValue()],
                    [26, 75 + randValue()],
                    [27, 80 + randValue()],
                    [28, 85 + randValue()],
                    [29, 90 + randValue()],
                    [30, 95 + randValue()]
                ];
```

I have a user table and I need to create an hash grouping and counting the users of the last month by date.

So:

```
User.group('date(created_at)').count
```

etc... the first value is the day of the month and the second value is the number of users that have submitted their registration on that day.

When I have my hash, how can I pass the hash to the JS?

Comment: You could store it in a data-attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can try `as_json` and stuff it inside a data attribute:

```
<div id="page_views" data-users="<%= @user_registrations.as_json %>"></div>
```

Comment: I've done it, now I have a lot of `data-contents-01="0" data-contents-02="1" data-contents-03="3" data-contents-04="0" data-contents-05="0" data-contents-06="0" data-contents-07="0" data-contents-08="0"` and I don't know how can i handle them in my js file!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I generate my data through this:

```
u = User.group("EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at)").count.to_a
#=> [[26.0, 2], [27.0, 2]]
```

If your script is in a `.erb` file, I can directly pass this value to your js variable (based on your sample input above).

Like this:

```
var pageviews = <%= u %>;
```